# Show that the radius of convergence is 1

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

Assume $\Sigma b_n$ converges, $\Sigma (-1)^nb_n$ diverges. Show the power series $\Sigma b_n x^n$ has a radius of convergence of 1.

My attempt is to write the power series centered at 0 and find two x value differ by 2, but when I pick x value as 1 and -1, I don't see how one of them converge and the other one diverges.

Comment: What do the original conditions tell you about the result of the ratio test for $\sum b_n$?

Comment: I think I kind of get it now. So the limit of b_n+1 /b_n is both greater and equal to 1, an smaller and equal to 1, so the limit is 1.

Comment: Precisely.  So when you make them the coefficients of a power series $\ldots$.

Comment: You cannot use the ratio test for $b_n,$ as $b_n $ is not necessarily positive. Even if it is nonnegative it  may vanish for infinitely many $n.$ Rather, go back to the definition of the radius of convergence, not the formula for its value.